# Using @Value to inject property to constructor, SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E (4.1.6)

Tags: spring, spring-annotations, spring-el, spring-java-config

I read a post about authentication with facebook, http://www.jasha.eu/blogposts/2013/09/retrieve-facebook-profile-data-java-spring-social.html

he use autowired to inject 3 arguments to the constructor. which gives me SpelEvaluationException.

My project, I add a config.properties under /src/

> facebook.clientId=237473571343
>
> facebook.clientSecret=9iuwijig[sa[w90u2tjgjgj
>
> application.host=http://localhost:8080

and the constructor

```
@Controller
public class FacebookSpringSocialAuthenticator {
  public static final String STATE = "state";
  private String applicationHost;
  private FacebookConnectionFactory facebookConnectionFactory;

  @Autowired
  public FacebookSpringSocialAuthenticator(
      @Value("#{properties['facebook.clientId']}") 
        String clientId,
      @Value("#{properties['facebook.clientSecret']}") 
        String clientSecret,
      @Value("#{properties['application.host']}") 
        String applicationHost) {
    this.applicationHost = applicationHost;
    facebookConnectionFactory = 
      new FacebookConnectionFactory(clientId, clientSecret);
  }
}
```

after search and reading discussions and docs, I still don't figure out what to do.

1. the #{} is spring EL support, don't know how to use it, and don't know the difference to ${}
2. if I change to @Value("${facebook.clientId}"), there will be no exception, then I use debug mode to read the value of clientId, it does not show  237473571343, it shows ${facebook.clientId}, is that working correctly?

Comment: just tested it, facebook gives me invalid app id ${facebook.clientId}, so change from # to $ is not working. I guess I am missing something, spring doesn't recognize my properties file as a bean.

Comment: If you don't have a `*PlaceHolderConfigurer` nothing will happen, also just slapping a properties file somewher doesn't get it loaded. Show us some configuration. Also if you are using maven the file should be in `src/main/resources` and not in `src`.

Comment: you are right, I think I didn't have PlaceHolderConfigurer, my code works after adding <util:properties id="config" location="classpath:config.properties" /> to servlet.xml. but I don't know the difference between util:properties and PlaceHolderConfigurer, are they the same?

Comment: No they aren't and it shouldn't work with that, unless you named it `properties`. You should use a `<context:properties-placeholder />` instead.

Comment: Deinum answer is correct. don't know how to make it as answered.

Answer (score 3):

```
@Value("#{properties['facebook.clientId']}")
```

In your `@Value` annotation you are using a SpEL expression. In your case it is going to look for a `Map` or `Properties` object named `properties` and try to find a property with the key `facebook.clientId`.

To make it work you need to add the following

```
<util:properties id="properties" location="config.properties" />
```

Although this works I would strongly suggest to use a `*PlaceHolderConfigurer` instead of using SpEL.`First add a``tag to your configuration, next change your`@Value` to simply use properties.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="config.properties" />
```

Then your `@Value` can be like

```
@Value("${facebook.clientId}")
```

The added advantage of this is that you could also use system or environment properties to do some configuration (or override parts of your configuration).